# Selenium WebDriver drag and drop to scrollbar

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop, selenium-webdriver, scrollbar

I have issue with Selenium WebDriver drag-and-drop. It didn't want drop to webelement in scroll-bar.
I tried this:

```
new Actions(SeleniumDriver.getDriver())).dragAndDrop(element, target).build().perform();
```

also tried by using offsets:

```
(new Actions(SeleniumDriver.getDriver()))
           .dragAndDropBy(element, xoffset, yoffset).build().perform();
```

and try use:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(SeleniumDriver.getDriver());
builder.clickAndHold(element).build().perform();
builder.moveToElement(target).build().perform();
builder.release(target).build().perform();
```

Any body know working solutions for scroll-bars? Thank's for any help.

Comment: I noticed what bottom scroll-bar moves when selenium want drop in aria with scroll-bars. But element didn't dropped.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution by using  Java Robot class.

1. Switch chrome to full screen:

   ```
   DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("--kiosk", "test-type");
   dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(dc);
   ```
2. Get coordinates of start and destination element:

   ```
   // start coordinates
   int startX = new Integer(element.getLocation().x);
   int startY = new Integer(element.getLocation().y);

   // destination dimensions
   int startWidth = new Integer(element.getSize().width);
   int startHeight = new Integer(element.getSize().height);

   // destination coordinates
   int destinationX = new Integer(target.getLocation().x);
   int destinationY = new Integer(target.getLocation().y);

   // destination dimensions
   int destinationWidth = new Integer(target.getSize().width);
   int destinationHeight = new Integer(target.getSize().height);

   // work out destination coordinates
   int endX = Math.round(destinationX + (destinationWidth / 2));
   int endY = Math.round(destinationY + (destinationHeight / 2));
   int sX = Math.round(startX + (startWidth / 2));
   int sY = Math.round(startY + (startHeight / 2));
   ```
3. Use Java Robot class for drag and drop:

   ```
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.mouseMove(sX, sY);
   robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   robot.mouseMove(endX, endY);
   robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are trying to drag the right element.
Maybe that element is not dragable, it could be an inner element that is dragable.

Comment: I drag <img draggable="true" src="somelink">

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas;

- A small sleep is required after the click and hold. I have tested applications which required 100ms of hold until the drag and drop us initialized.
- It could be using HTML 5 drag and drop which last I tried wasn't supported by Selenium
- wrong element as suggested by user3723314

Comment: I tried sleep. It didn't help. My project use HTML 4.