# Sendkeys and javascript executor aren't working, how do I get text into this textbox with Selenium Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to enter text into the min price and max price textboxes under the price option for Airbnb.com, for example:

https://www.airbnb.com/s/Miami--Florida--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=august&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=july&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=weekend_trip&date_picker_type=calendar&adults=4&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=filter_change&place_id=ChIJEcHIDqKw2YgRZU-t3XHylv8

But I cannot get any of my input to send over the default entries of min price 10 and max price 1000. I've tried send keys and the best I could do was get the entries to 0 by sending ctrl + all + del keys and after that the default values just came back. I saw that when send keys doesn't work, javascript executor can be a good alternative so I also tried that even with waiting for the elements to be clickable, but nothing is working. Here is my code and commented out is my failed attempt with send keys:

```
        # price_min = self.driver.find_element_by_id("price_filter_min")

        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "price_filter_min"))
        )
        # price_min.clear()
        # price_min.click()
        # price_min.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a', Keys.BACKSPACE)
        # price_min.send_keys(min_price)

        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1]);", element, 354)

        # price_max = self.driver.find_element_by_id("price_filter_max")

        element2 = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "price_filter_max"))
        )

        # price_max.clear()
        # price_max.click()
        # price_max.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a', Keys.BACKSPACE)
        # price_max.send_keys(max_price)

        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element2)
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1]);", element2, 800)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try with css selector '[id^=price_filter_min]' There seems to be more to the id than price_filter_min (so this selects by how it starts)

Comment: Where exactly are these textboxes `min price and max price textboxes`  in the shared URL ?

Answer (score 0):

These inputs are not really inputs to set the mix and max values.
They only reflecting limits set by horizontal slide bars.
Try swiping them as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012330/how-to-swipe-to-right-or-left-with-selenium) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198898/selenium-webdriver-drag-and-drop-to-scrollbar)
Alternatively you can try setting the scroll bar attributes directly. See if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code to replicate your scenario. Please take a look into it and let me know if you don't understand anything.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(
    'https://www.airbnb.co.in/s/Miami--Florida--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&'
    'flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=august&flexible_trip_dates%5B%5D=july&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=weekend_trip&date_'
    'picker_type=calendar&adults=4&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=filter_change&place_id=ChIJEcHID'
    'qKw2YgRZU-t3XHylv8&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1625828364_YTljYWI4OTA5ZjZh')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
action = ActionChains(driver)

# Press OK for Cookie Preference
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//button[text()='OK'])[2]"))).click()
except:
    pass

# Click on Price Button
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Price"]/ancestor::button'))).click()

# The minimum value present for the slider is 750. So you should not change it to 0. 
minimum_Scroll = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Minimum Price"]')))

# Here for the maximum price you can use the action class with drag_and_drop_by_offset method.
maximum_Scroll = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Maximum Price"]')))

# This action will drag the slider to near 10,000Rs [Currency Coming in Rs because I am in India, But you can adjust the Xoffset as per your requirement].
action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(maximum_Scroll, -202, 0).perform()

# Clicking save button
SaveBtn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'filter-panel-save-button'))).click()
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.